# PHP MySQL Top 5 Referers Function

Tags: php, mysql, function, ranking

I have a table called `users` which looks like:

-id
-email
-login
-admin
-coins
-cash
-premium
-IP
-pass
-ref
-signup 
-online 
-promote
-activate
-banned 
-rec_hash
-country    
-c_changes  
-sex    
-daily_bonus

If say user with id 81 referred 10 people then those 10 people would have "81" in their `ref` column.

I would like to create a top 5 referral table but I'm having trouble with the query and displaying that in PHP, would anybody be able to help?

I FORGOT TO MENTION IF THEY HAVE NO REFERRAL IT SHOWS AS `0` HOW WOULD I EXCLUDE 0 FROM BEING SHOWN AS A REFERRAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT ref, COUNT(*) AS num FROM users
GROUP BY ref ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5
```

But that will just get you the 5 IDs, rather than their user rows. You can then perform a further query to get the actual rows. Alternatively, use the above query with a join to do it all in one.

Comment: How would I get their `login` by using your query?

Comment: @cal Do you agree with me, a normalization for this table will be better? In other word, creating another table for reference?

Comment: @LiamGordon just add login, after SELECT

Answer (score 0):

> IF THEY HAVE NO REFERRAL IT SHOWS AS 0

messy design - this should be null. Regardless...

```
 SELECT u.login, ilv.referred
 FROM
 (SELECT ref, COUNT(*) AS referred
   FROM users
  WHERE ref IS NOT NULL
  AND ref>0
  GROUP BY ref
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 0,5) ilv
INNER JOIN users u
ON ilv.ref=users.id
ORDER BY ilv.referred DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or and SQL like this:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(*) as referrers FROM users r JOIN users u ON r.ref = u.id
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY referrers DESC LIMIT 5
```

It is faster to use just one statement even with a join on the same table.